# How to iterate over an array and use the values in a command in shell?

Tags: api, shell, curl

A Noob here. I am trying to call an API endpoint with curl to get list of (users) to use later in another subsequent API call with a while loop.

Curl request:

- `users=$(curl https://localhost/users/)`

When I echo the response this is what I get?

- `["Jane","Joe","random","Person"]`

How can I loop through all users in that array, to use them in subsequent API call?

Ps: I am using shell for this :)

Comment: Assuming the result of the curl is actually an array, you could use [this guide](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop-array/). You could further refine the question by  running the curl command showing the actual results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I loop through all users in that array, to use them in subsequent API call?

If you have `jq` installed, you can use it to extract the users from the JSON array:

```
for user in `curl https://localhost/users/ | jq -r '.[]'`
do  echo $user
done
```

Another variant, using `tr`:

```
for user in `curl https://localhost/users/ | tr '[",]' \ `
do  echo $user
done
```

Comment: unfortunately jq is not installed on that box, and I cannot install anything on were this is going to run eventually.

Comment: I added a variant without `jq`.